# Dataframe of lists: get the values having length more than 1

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, sublist

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[2]]), columns=['col'])
```

I need to reach finally below sub-list:

```
    col
0   [1, 2]
1   [1, 2, 3]
```

Which means I need to "**get the rows having length > 1**" or "**drop rows having length <= 1**". How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter using `.loc` and set a condition on the `len`gth of the `'col'` column, then, use `reset_index` on the resulting dataframe to ignore the index of the old dataframe:

```
print(df.loc[df.col.str.len() > 1].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
         col
0     [1, 2]
1  [1, 2, 3]
```